# C++ interface style programming. Need a way out

Tags: c++, interface, extending

```
template <typename T>
class BaseQueue
{
    public :
    virtual void push_back(T value) = 0;
    //other  virtual methods
};

template <typename T>
class BaseDeque: public virtual BaseQueue<T>
{
    public:
        virtual void push_front(T value) = 0;
        //other virtual methods
};

//Realisation
template <typename T>
class VectorQueue: public BaseQueue<T>
{
    typedef typename std::vector<T> array;
    private: array adata;
    public:
    VectorQueue()
    {
       adata = array();
    }

    void push_back(T value)
    {
        adata.push_back(value);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class VectorDeque: virtual public VectorQueue<T>, virtual protected BaseDeque<T>//, 
{
    void push_front(T value)
    {
        VectorQueue::adata.push_front(value);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VectorDeque<int> vd = VectorDeque<int>();//here is a error

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

I have such error: "C2259: 'VectorDeque' : cannot instantiate abstract class ...". How can I fix it? Class VectorQueue has realize every virtual method of BaseQueue class already. But the compiler doesn't know it. The only way I see is to write something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class VectorDeque: virtual public VectorQueue<T>, virtual protected BaseDeque<T>//, 
{
    void push_front(T value)
    {
        VectorQueue::adata.push_front(value);
    }
    void push_back(T value)
    {
        VectorQueue::push_back(value);
    }
    //repeat it fo every virtual method of BaseQueue class (interface)
};
```

But it's awful.

Comment: This is the dreaded [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).  BaseDeque pulls in push_back from BaseQueue, and it's unimplemented in VectorDeque.  The implementation of VectorQueue::push_back isn't seen as an implementation of BaseDeque::push_back.  Sadly, all I can offer is an explanation of why it won't work; I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` from `BaseQueue` isn't implemented on the `BaseDeque` side of the inheritance chain, and thus the childmost class is still abstract.

I think you're trying to force a class relationship here that shouldn't exist. Note how in the standard library `deque` and `vector` are distinct container types and things like `queue` adapt those containers to very precise interfaces rather than trying to inherit.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you solve your diamond issue (or follow @Mark B's advice and keep them separate), you have a few other issues in there:

```
template <typename T>
class VectorQueue: public BaseQueue<T>
{
    typedef typename std::vector<T> array;
    private: array adata;   // if this is private, VectorDeque can't reach it

    public:
    // constructors have an initializer section
    // member variables should be initialized there, not in the body
    VectorQueue()
    // : adata()  // however, no need to explicitly call default constructor
    {
       // adata = array();
    }
};


template <typename T>
class VectorDeque: virtual public VectorQueue<T>, virtual protected BaseDeque<T>
{
    void push_front(T value)
    {
        // if adata is protected, you can just access it.  No need for scoping
        /*VectorQueue::*/  adata.push_front(value);
        // Error:  std::vector doesn't have a method push_front.
        // Perhaps you meant to use std::list?
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance and static polymorphism are of help, for instance:

```
// Abstract bases
template <typename T, typename Val> 
class BaseQueue 
{     
public :     
    void push_back(Val val)
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->push_back(val); 
    }
    // ...
};  
template <typename T, typename Val> 
class BaseDeque
{     
public:         
    void push_front(Val val)
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->push_front(val); 
    }
    // ...
};

// Concrete class
#include <deque>
template <typename Val> 
class QueueDeque: 
    public BaseQueue<QueueDeque<Val>, Val>,
    public BaseDeque<QueueDeque<Val>, Val>
{   
    std::deque<Val> vals;
public:
    void push_front(Val val)
    {
        vals.push_front(val); 
    }
    void push_back(Val val)
    {
        vals.push_back(val); 
    }
    // etc..
};  
int main() 
{     
    QueueDeque<int> vd;// no more error      
    vd.push_front(5);
    vd.push_back(0);
    return 0; 
}
```